# Underscores in MYSQL table column names for org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions throws Exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm definitely a noob with Hibernate and am struggling to Query my database when table column names have underscores.

From what I've read, the underscore is treated like a wildcard. So, the solution is to remove it and camelCase the column name. However, that isn't working for me either. I would really appreciate some help here.

Here is the SQL table creation:

[image]

Here is the function where I attempt to Query:

[image]

When I call this function though, I get the following stack trace:

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userId of....

I've tried it with multiple variations of userId: user_id, userId, user_ID, userID, userid & nothing works. I would really appreciate some help here. Thanks in advance. One other weird thing is that the camelCasing works if I do it for just publishId. It just doesn't work for both of them...

Here is the Java class with it's annotations:

[image]

Comment: Please, show the mappings for the `Publisher` entity.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated the post to include the Publisher class with mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPQL (HQL) you have to use property names:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userEmail", user));
```

This is one of the benefits of ORM frameworks like JPA (and of course its providers like Hibernate and others): you use object-oriented constructs in queries as well.

Comment: I wish I could give you more upvotes! You, my friend, are a life saver!!! Thanks! That was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `userEmail` in your criteria because the the `user_id` field is named `userEmail`.

`criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userEmail", user))`